# Image keeps its aspect ratio but its frame doesn't

Tags: swiftui

In the following code, I did some experiments and please note that I have made some custom extensions for gradients (not shown here), but they are not important, you can ignore them.

```
import SwiftUI
import PlaygroundSupport

struct ContentView: View {
    
    // body
    var body: some View {
        
        // background image
        let image = Image("some_image"))
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFit()
            .frame(maxWidth: 300)
        
        // image mask
        let imageMask = Image(systemName: "heart.fill")
            .resizable().scaledToFit().frame(width: 100).opacity(0.8)
        
        // text mask
        let textMask = Text("SwiftUI is Awesome!")
            .font(.title).fontWeight(.bold)
        
        return HStack {
            VStack {
                
                // my custom extension (not important)
                Gradient.vertical  (.red  , .orange)
                Gradient.horizontal(.green, .blue  )
                Gradient.diagonal  (.pink , .purple)
                
                image
                    .overlay(imageMask.border(Color.blue), alignment: .topLeading)
                    .border(Color.green)
                
                image.mask(imageMask)
                
            }.border(Color.blue)
        }
    }
    
}

PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(ContentView())
```

and the result is:

[image]

My question is: why does the image keep its aspect ratio, but not its frame (the green border)?

Comment: Let's approach it from a different angle.  What are you trying/hoping to achieve?

Comment: @vacawama I want the (green) frame to match the image, no extra padding on both sides.

Comment: I'm kind of in the way of getting it, I should have set the `image`'s frame to be something like `.frame(minHeight: 80)`, not `.frame(maxWidth: 300)`, right?

Comment: Or remove the `.frame(maxWidth: 300)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scaledToFit()` is forcing the image to maintain its aspect ratio while fitting inside the parent view, which in its case is the **frame**.

However, the frame will try to extend as much as you allow it, i.e. 300, which is more than the width of the scaled down image.

You can observe this even further by setting a `maxHeight: 100`

Comment: you said the frame will try to extend as much as it can, then why the image isn't as wide as those gradients?

Comment: The frame will extend much as you allow it, which is the maxWidth of 300 and that appears to be less than the gradients. If you remove the .frame modifier, the border will be around the image.

Comment: Also, you might wonder if you remove the .frame modifier, why doesn't the image scale to fill the whole width of the container.
It's aspect ratio is limited by the sibling views (gradients & imageMask) occupying space in the VStack. If you remove some of the other views you can notice the difference.